# adjusting video size and keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I'm trying make an embedded `Vimeo` video look smaller on an web page. Currently it's responsive, and want to keep it responsive. It's looking too big on web right now (happy with mobile size) though - how do it make it smaller?

```css
.video_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video_wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_wrapper">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/24799548" width="700" height="525" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you like to use `Bootstrap`.you can do it using `col-md` `col-sm` classes

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the `width` and `height` from:

```
.video_wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and set it to 90% for example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
.video_wrapper iframe {
    width: 75%;
    height:75%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

looks that I've put the background:transparent and put the margin:auto to keep it centered.